# How to setup a debugger in QtCreator?

Tags: debugging, qt-creator

I don't have a debugger. When I click on debug, a window pops up stating "no debugger set up". I don't have any idea how to fix it so I need step-by-step instructions for dummies. If need be, a download link would be very useful(x64).

Comment: Which OS are you using?  Do you have the debugger installed for that compiler?  For Windows it is not as intuitive as it should be.  Mac and Linux is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

### MingW

Install MingW when installing Qt, and it gets everything in the paths correctly.

### MSVC 2010

Install the tool chain through Visual Studio or Visual Studio Express and then hunt down where the debugger gets installed to.  Qt may be able to auto detect it, if it was already installed before you install Qt Creator.

The Qt Creator documentation is pretty good, too.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.2/creator-debugger-engines.html#installing-native-debuggers

Comment: how do you think hunt down where the debugger gets installed to.

Comment: To use the CDB debugger, you must install the Debugging tools for Windows. You can download them from [Download and Install Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009/).